# How to integrate opeanam ,web agent and java application?

Tags: apache, tomcat, openam

I have followed the below link for integration:
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/getting-started/

Step -1.configured our host file as
127.0.0.1    localhost openam.example.com www.example.com
step:2.Installed Apache HTTP Server 2.2
and I am able to Browse to the home page, such as http://www.example.com:8383

Step.3.Installed Apache Tomcat(apache-tomcat-7.0.55)
     I deployed opeam.war inside the webapps andable to access through browser
    with openam.example.com:8080/openam/
Step:4: Configured a Policy in OpenAM

step:5:Created a Web Policy Agent Profile
     Name
WebAgent
    Password
password
    Configuration
Centralized
   Server URL
   openam.example.com:8080/openam
  Agent URL
   example.com:8383

Step:6:Installed OpenAM Web Policy Agent
**It is working fine .**

But, When I try to protect our java application using the Agent Url as
openam.example.com:8080/ApplicationName
We get the following error when we click on the Create option
->
Error "Deployment URI in agent URL is not allowed".
please do guide me or give me feedback in case, I am following a wrong approach while giving Agent Url as our "java Application URL" .

Comment: I guess you want to access the application through mod_proxy_ajp/http through the 'reverse-proxy' where the agent is deployed and  the application is deployed in the same container as OpenAM ....

This requires a good understanding of OpenAM ... not something you should start with.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you have to use either HTTP_HEADER or HTTP_COOKIE comm mechanism between web server (with web agent) and your J2EE application. You could use Profile Attributes processing section to map  LDAP attributes to HTTP headers and in your java application you could read that headers.

Answer (score 0):

openam has a J2EE agent to protect java applications. You seem to be using the web agent which isn't recommended for j2ee agents.